# Auto detect modem port when using gammu

Tags: c++, c, sms-gateway, gammu

I want to create a sms gateway in C/C++ using **gammu**.
How can I detect the modem port plugged in PC automatically. Is there a way to do that in C/C++?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, gammu uses database-based application. If you have configured your gammurc and smsdrc, it will be loaded in service at startup. If it is connected you just setup your code to read mysql and of course gammu database.